# What is the correct pronunciation of CAGR?

Tags: terminology, growth

My apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this, but it is financing nomenclature.  I didn't find this question anywhere on SE, and I have been dissatisfied with Google results.

I have heard several pronunciations of the acronym CAGR:

- Rhymes with bagger
- Keh-gar or cay-gar (almost like kegger)
- Rhymes with jogger

It seems that regardless of pronunciation, people understand via context, but I was curious if there is a correct way.

Comment: Why is the pronunciation is of any concern ? Just spell out the letters as C.A.G.R. Most acronyms have no official pronunciations.

Comment: @DumbCoder I strongly disagree that there are no official pronunciations.  Perhaps official in this usage is strong, but certainly there are commonly accepted pronunciations.  You are confusing acronyms with initialisms.  I have only heard NASA or SCUBA or ASAP pronounced a single way.  This has not been the case with the acronym CAGR, in my experience.

Comment: Financial columnist Morgan Housel [wondered the same thing](https://twitter.com/morganhousel/status/519493181189406720).

Comment: `people understand via context` You just said this. So the relevance of  CAGR is with context so it doesn't hinder you if you pronounce it any way possible. As @JoeTaxpayer mentioned I have also never heard it being spelled as a word on any of the business channels I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

I always hear people pronounce it to rhyme with "bagger".

Comment: For people with a Minnesotan accent, the vowel is the "a" in "lack", not the "a" in "bag" (or "lake").

Answer (score 0):

> Most readers probably know that an acronym is an invented word made up
>   of the initial letters or syllables of other words, like NASA or NATO.
>   Fewer probably know that an initialism is a type of acronym that
>   cannot be pronounced as a word, but must be read letter-by-letter,
>   like FBI or UCLA.

A quote from [Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/acronym-vs-initialism/). CAGR is an initialism, and should not be pronounced.

Comment: I think "shouldn't be pronounced" is an overstatement! :-)  Anything can be pronounced.  You just mean it should be pronounced "see ey gee arr".

Comment: Ok, agreed. Try saying it to rhyme with bagger and see the looks you get.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm really not trying to be combative, but I work for a Fortune 500 company and commonly hear it pronounced.  Unfortunately, I hear it pronounced different ways and hence the question.  In my experience in the corporate world, this is never said "see ey gee arr".

Comment: Well. First. I am not sensitive. I can be wrong, and will be wrong again. I am 54, and have never heard it pronounced on CNBC which I watch quite a bit. The fact that you don't hear it the same way, or rather, hear it many ways, implies there no set answer. At least EBIDTA seems to be pronounced consistently. If I heard 'kagger', I might say "what?" unless context was obvious.